# Looking for a string in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use the regex module in Python. For example, I have two strings:

```
Профессиональная ГИС "Панорама" (версия 12.4.0, для платформы "x64")
Профессиональная ГИС "Панорама" (версия 12.4.0, для платформы "x32")
```

Numbers after 12 are changeable and can be more than two numbers. How can I catch, for example, all first strings?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: what does `all first string` mean in your case?

Comment: @ScottHunter it was my fault not to demonstate efforts. But now it doesn't matter for me, duty to below answers i understood how do i have to work with regexp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what the conditions are. Based on your comments I think you look for the following regex:

```
r"Профессиональная ГИС \"Панорама\" \(версия 12(\.\d+){2,}, для платформы \"x(32|64)\"\)"
```

This will match any sequence of dots and numbers after the `12.` (so for instance `12.4.51.3.002` is allowed), and furthermore both `x64` and `x32` are allowed (not `x42`).

You can test the regex on [**regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/qB2HFa/1).

Comment: Thank you very much, now i understood more.  I have tried this service, but maybe have had some dullness

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below one. If you have optional numbers after 12, you can include the `?` symbol to match the regular expression.

```
 Профессиональная ГИС "Панорама" \(версия 12.[0-9]?[0-9].[0-9]?[0-9], для платформы "x(32|64)"\)
```